# Code crashes because of an uninitialized variable even if I don't actually use it

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, language-lawyer

Why does the following code crashes at run-time in Visual Studio 2012?

```
void foo(void* ptr)
{

}

int main()
{
  void* ptr;
  foo(ptr);
}
```

> Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'ptr' is being used without
>   being initialized.

I know that this error can be disabled by setting the "Basic Runtime Checks" option to "Default" but I don't see any reason why I should have this error when I don't actually dereference the specified pointer.

Is it an intented behavior?

Comment: Sure, you are passing the pointer value by value.  I don't see any reason why you'd ever want to write code like this.  Well, don't make it habit and don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: It's actually _used_ at the function call.

Comment: You are evaluating an expression whose value is indeterminate. The standard says that's UB. If it's not UB, what's its value defined to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even just passing a pointer to a function you are "using" it and it's technically undefined behavior if the value is not initialized.

The reason is that there are hardware platforms where pointers are passed in special registers and setting them with an invalid value will generate an hardware trap **when the register is set**, an not when and if the pointer is actually used.

The solution is not disabling the check, but initialize the pointers before using them. If you don't know a value to use then just go for `nullptr`.

Comment: "Even just passing a pointer to a function you are "using" it and it's technically undefined behavior" -- could you quote the standard?

Comment: It depends exactly which standard you mean, but it will have some version of, "*.... if an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined...*" Here, evaluating `ptr` in the function call produces an indeterminate value.

Comment: Ok, I've created a separate question because of this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681349/is-passing-an-unitialized-variable-to-another-function-ub